# How to name aggregate columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm using Spark in Scala and my aggregated columns are anonymous. Is there a convenient way to rename multiple columns from a dataset? I thought about imposing a schema with `as` but the key column is a struct (due to the `groupBy` operation), and I can't find out how to define a `case class` with a `StructType` in it.

I tried defining a schema as follows:

```
val returnSchema = StructType(StructField("edge", StructType(StructField("src", IntegerType, true),
                                                             StructField("dst", IntegerType), true)), 
                              StructField("count", LongType, true))
edge_count.as[returnSchema]
```

but I got a compile error:

```
Message: <console>:74: error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (fields: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType <and>
  (fields: java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType <and>
  (fields: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField, org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField, Boolean)
       val returnSchema = StructType(StructField("edge", StructType(StructField("src", IntegerType, true),
```

Comment: Could you show us the code? So maybe I can formulate a better approach?

Comment: Pretend you have a dataset with three columns. Group by the first two, and count by the third. The key is then a tuple. I'm on Spark 1.6.2. Thanks @AlbertoBonsanto!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using `alias`es with the `select` statement; e.g.,

```
ds.select($"key.src".as[Short], 
          $"key.dst".as[Short], 
          $"sum(count)".alias("count").as[Long])
```

First I had to use `printSchema` to determine the derived column names:

```
> ds.printSchema

root
 |-- key: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- src: short (nullable = false)
 |    |-- dst: short (nullable = false)
 |-- sum(count): long (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 22):

The best solution is to name your columns explicitly, e.g.,

```
df
  .groupBy('a, 'b)
  .agg(
    expr("count(*) as cnt"),
    expr("sum(x) as x"),
    expr("sum(y)").as("y")
  )
```

If you are using a dataset, you have to provide the type of your columns, e.g., `expr("count(*) as cnt").as[Long]`.

You can use the DSL directly but I often find it to be more verbose than simple SQL expressions.

If you want to do mass renames, use a `Map` and then `foldLeft` the dataframe.

Comment: This gives me a type mismatch error; the input is a dataset.

Comment: That's because `expr()` returns `Column` and you need a `TypedColumn` in the dataset API. I've updated the answer to show a dataset example.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sim's answer that the most convenient way is to name columns explicitly while creation time. Here is just another way how to alias columns (without using `expr`):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "a"),
  (2, "b"),
  (3, "c")
).toDF("number", "word")

val aggDf = df.agg(
  collect_list(struct(col("number"), col("word"))) as "myStruct",
  sum(col("number")) as "mySum",
  count(col("*")) as "myCnt"
)

aggDf.printSchema

// |-- myStruct: array (nullable = true)
// |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |-- number: integer (nullable = false)
// |    |    |-- word: string (nullable = true)
// |-- mySum: long (nullable = true)
// |-- myCnt: long (nullable = false)

aggDf.show()

// +------------------------+-----+-----+
// |myStruct                |mySum|myCnt|
// +------------------------+-----+-----+
// |[[1, a], [2, b], [3, c]]|6    |3    |
// +------------------------+-----+-----+
```